# How to join 3 tables with Bookshelf in Node.js

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

So i have table `user`, table `book` for example and table `user_book_xref`.

`user_book_xref` has `user_id` fk to `id` in `user`

`user_book_xref` has `book_id` fk to `id` in `book`

how do i select all the books from user with `id` = 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a belongsToMany relationship and since you have named your joining table outside of the convention, you will need to specify it in the function. You will then need to fetch the user and pass the relationship in the fetch options.

```
// set up models with relationships
var Book = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'book'
});
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'user',
    books: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(Book, 'user_book_xref');
    }
});

// query the user using withRelated
return User.forge({id: 1})
.fetch({withRelated:['books']})
.then(function(result) {
    // return only the book
    return result.toJSON().books;
});
```

Comment: it works great. btw, what's the naming convention so that bookshelf can pick it up automatically?

Comment: table1_table2 in alphabetical order

Comment: what do u mean by alphabetical order ? so it should be `book_user` instead of `user_book`?

Comment: Correct, alphabetical order of the table names. It is documented on the project site